# Eclipse IDE: Vertical text

Tags: android, eclipse, text

I've spent hours on youtube, google and by trying to figure this out, I hope you guys have the answer:

I want to have some vertical text boxes, containing the dates of the year. In the graphical layout it looks just like i want it:
(like this)

januar

1. jan
2. jan
3. jan
4. jan
5. jan
6. jan
7. jan
8. jan
9. jan

But when I use the emulator, it suddenly looks like this:

januar

1.jan 2.

jan
3.

jan
4.

jan 5.

jan 6.

jan 7.

jan 8.

jan 9.

jan
(Or something like this)

--

my xml looks as follows

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Kbh" >

    <ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="57dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="3dp"
        android:text="DATO
januar 
 1. jan
 2. jan
 3. jan
 4. jan
 5. jan
 6. jan
 7. jan
 8. jan
 9. jan
10. jan
11. jan
12. jan
13. jan
14. jan
15. jan
....

29. dec
30. dec 
31. dec" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

What am I missing?

-Chris

Answer (score 0):

First of all: this will be a very, very long list!!
If I were you I would use something like a CalendarView. There are plenty of open source libraries that you can find, but since API 11 there is a native one: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html

If you (for some reason) want to keep your current list implementation, then you are better of using a ListView instead of TextView in a ScrollView: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   android:text="januar \n 1. jan \n 2. jan \n "etc
```

and dont always trust your XML gui try it on the device or emulator.